# How to override inline style which is set in javascript with CSS Hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styling

I'm using some font awesome icons in an  element inside a href. The color of these has to be set in javascript, based on some conditions. Which works fine, BUT on `:hover` only the href text changes color, even though the color is set to !important in CSS.
If I remove the inline color set in JS for the icons it works fine with `:hover`.

Shouldn't !important override the inline style set in js?

My element where iconcolor is the issue:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#grad.com"><i style="height:20px; width:20px; color:green;" class="fas fa-ban" id="jsonicon"></i>Grad </a>
```

Removing the `elem.iconcolor` and not setting any color in JS works, but then again I won't be able to add color on conditions.

And my CSS:

```
    .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-submenu:focus > a, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a {
    /*color: inherit;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(0,122,255,255); /*Color on nav items on hover */
    background-image: none;
    color: white !important;
}
```

I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2 on top of this.

Full html structure:

```css
/* 


    #embeda013f208-3363-a68f-3b07-1a1824410343_0 ul.nav li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu

    set to display:block when editing in browser, to see changes instantly. 

*/


#navigationDiv {
    /*margin-top: 46px;*/
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 46px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar-inner {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

ul.nav li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}

navbar sticky-top navbar-light bg-light {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 46px;
}

/*#novobarcontainer{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}*/

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: fixed;
    top: 46px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}


.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 7px 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

    .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-submenu:focus > a, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a {
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: rgba(0,122,255,255); /*Color on nav items on hover */
        background-image: none;
        color: white;
    }

.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

/*This is the color on the small arrow on the submenu*/
.dropdown-submenu > a:after {
    border-left-color: black;
}

    .dropdown-submenu > a:after:hover {
        border-left-color: white;
    }


/* change color on hover root element*/
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    color: black;
    text-shadow: none;
}


    .navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
        color: white;
        background-color: rgba(0,122,255,255);
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/regular.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="navigationDiv" class="navbar-inner"><ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#undergrad.com"><i style="height:20px; width:20px; color:red;" class="fas fa-ban" id="jsonicon"></i>UnderGrad </a>
<ul class="submenu dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#art.undergrad.com"><i style="height:20px; width:20px; color:blue;" class="fas fa-ban" id="jsonicon"></i>art.undergrad </a>
<ul class="submenu dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#classic.art.undergrad.com"><i style="height:20px; width:20px; color:green;" class="fas fa-ban" id="jsonicon"></i>classic.art.undergrad </a>
<ul class="submenu dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#hey"><i style="height:20px; width:20px; color:#3CB371;" class="fas fa-ban" id="jsonicon"></i>hey </a>
<ul class="submenu dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#music.grad.com"><i style="height:20px; width:20px; color:red;" class="fas fa-ban" id="jsonicon"></i>music.grad </a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#science.grad.com"><i style="height:20px; width:20px; color:black;" class="fas fa-ban" id="jsonicon"></i>science.grad </a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#grad.com"><i style="height:20px; width:20px; color:green;" class="fas fa-ban" id="jsonicon"></i>Grad </a>
<ul class="submenu dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#music.grad.com"><i style="height:20px; width:20px; color:#3CB371;" class="fas fa-ban" id="jsonicon"></i>music.grad </a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#science.grad.com"><i style="height:20px; width:20px; color:blue;" class="fas fa-ban" id="jsonicon"></i>science.grad </a>
<ul class="submenu dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#music.grad.com"><i style="height:20px; width:20px; color:green;" class="fas fa-ban" id="jsonicon"></i>music.grad </a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#science.grad.com"><i style="height:20px; width:20px; color:black;" class="fas fa-ban" id="jsonicon"></i>science.grad </a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some code (as a description of code is hard to work from)

Comment: `!important` should work, unless the inline style also has `!important` on it

Comment: Share your code, please. We can help you.

Comment: The inline code does not have important. I will edit the post with code.

Comment: @George added code!

Comment: _“Shouldnt !important override the inline style set in js?”_ - if you applied it to the element that actually _has_ the inline style, maybe … but you are not doing that. You applied `color: white !important;` to your `a` element with the rules you have shown, but not to the `i` inside it, which actually has the inline style. Of course the inline style wins here, !important or not.

Comment: @CBroe How would I target the `i` ? I have both the `#jsonicon` and `i` selectors. 

`.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus > i, .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover > i, .dropdown-submenu:focus > a > i, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a > i {
    color: white !important;
}` 

does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue. (Doesn’t necessarily need the JS parts, you can set the inline style static, but at least the HTML structure plus what ever CSS framework this uses, probably bootstrap, should be included.)

Comment: @CBroe Added full html structure and CSS. Added bootstrap 2.3.2 to snippet and font awesome. But it wont run correctly there. Im working on top of another system that I dont have any controll of, including some libs.

Comment: When I hover over Grad -> science.grad, the triangle there in the latter element _is_ white. Not sure where exactly the problem is supposed to be.

Comment: @CBroe My mistake. I forgot to add it to the "root" element in the menu, so I didnt really notice it worked on the submenues. Added it to root as well, and works as expected. Thanks for the pointer on selector. Please add your respons as an answer, and I can accept it.

Answer (score -1):

:hover will always overwrite element styling. Setting `a:hover { color: inherit; };` in css to overwrite font-awesomes css should do the trick.